# jQuery delay time seems to be wrong

Tags: jquery, delay

I want one div to fade out, for their to then be a brief pause, and after that for another div to fade in.

This is my attempt but ot doesn't work. The fadein animation starts before the fadeout one has finished.

```
    $('.nav .filters').fadeOut('200');
    $('.nav .map-r').delay('300').fadeIn('200');
```

Whats really weird is it works fine if I make each annimation 10x longer:

```
    $('.nav .filters').fadeOut('2000');
    $('.nav .map-r').delay('3000').fadeIn('2000');
```

Comment: Those look the same to me ;-)

Comment: Does fadeOut() take numbers as arguments instead of string literals representing numbers? Try removing the single quotes. Yes indeed, the single quotes are only for 'fast', 'slow', and the like, otherwise the argument should be a number sans quotes.

Comment: Works fine for me - just remove the quotes around the intervals... http://jsfiddle.net/KskfD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this, I think, is the answer, I just copied and pasted my comment above:

"Does fadeOut() take numbers as arguments instead of string literals representing numbers? Try removing the single quotes. Yes indeed, the single quotes are only for 'fast', 'slow', and the like, otherwise the argument should be a number sans quotes."

And the same goes for fadeIn() and delay(), and toggle(), etc. You could call it a jQuery convention.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the fadeIn() in the callback of the [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) so that it is executed when the fadeOut finishes

```
$('.nav .filters').fadeOut(200, function(){
   $('.nav .map-r').delay(300).fadeIn(200);
   //i'm not sure this works, if it doesn't just use setTimeout()
   //setTimeout(function(){$('.nav .map-r').fadeIn(200)}, 300);
});
```

Comment: You need to wrap the first `setTimeout()` argument in an anonymous function or you call it immediately and try to pass the return value as a callback to setTimeout.

Comment: @ThiefMaster yes yes i corrected that, i just don't know if delay() works used like this

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav .filters').fadeOut(200, function(){$('.nav .map-r').delay(300).fadeIn(200);});
```